# war manifest gets created in multiple locations

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, maven, war

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/manifest-mojo.html

When I run the above goal via maven, it creates the manifest under /src/main/webapp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as well as correctly under the target folder during war creation.

I would expect the plug-in to not generate additional artifacts under the source directory, how should I prevent this and it happens with the `2.2.1` version of the `maven-war-plugin`

Comment: There isn't a `2.2.1` version of the `maven-war-plugin` yet. The latest version is `2.1.1` - I assume that's the version you meant?

Answer (score 0):

It says right on that page you linked: "The manifest file is created in the warSourceDirectory." It's a configurable property. You can change it if you like. The one in target is probably just a maven-resources-plugin copy of the one in the src dir.

Comment: Does that mean I can move the warSourceDirectory to target to avoid this, will it have other implications during manifest generation?

Comment: I can't think of any reason that you wouldn't want to change where the manifest is generated, especially since the plugin has an option to let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `war:manifest` goal, just add the following configuration to your `maven-war-plugin`, as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-manifest-guide.html):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will automatically generate the `MANIFEST.MF` during the execution of the `war:war` goal only in the build output, and not in the source directory.

Comment: It doesn't work, MANIFEST.MF does get created in the source directory.

Comment: It shouldn't, per the maven-war-plugin documentation and various projects and tests where we use this configuration. Can you confirm that there isn't any other configuration in your project that would have an effect on this? Also, what maven goal(s) are you executing?

Comment: @Jason What Maven goals are you executing? Can you provide your POM and project layout? With the configuration I have provided above, simply running `mvn clean package` should only create the manifest in your build directory and built .war file, without modifying the contents of your source, as desired. We use this configuration quite frequently in our WARs, so I'm interested in what additional configuration you have or what goals you may be running that might cause a difference in behavior.